# Search +- day and month range in the last n years based on today's date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi: In MSSQL/TSQL here's the scenario: Lets say today's date is '2016-01-15' (January 15th 2016). I want to search data for +- 30 days BUT for the last 10 years. Therefore the search range would be: December 15 through February 15th but instead of just simply searching for +-30 days (December 15 2015 thru February 15 2016) from the date mentioned above, I want to search for all the data only between December 15 and February 15 for the last 10 years.

To put into perspective,I'm looking for weather patterns hence I need to stick close to the same time frame for each year for the last n number of years.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.

Comment: mysql, mariadb or mssql?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question could be improved if you show what you have tried so far, it helps people answer if you give them some code to start with, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how to ask a good question.

Comment: Some very interesting solutions so far and thanks to J Greene and Bistabil for the 2 solutions. Since I'm going to be running these queries ad hoc on many different machines, creating procedures there might not be possible. So far I have slightly modified my own requirements to keep the solution very slim. Instead of doing what I had originally asked for I modified my where clause to just the months from the +- date ranges and then doing a search on those months for whatever years the database has. For example:

Comment: Select Date, Temperature, Humidity from TableT
where month(date) between month(DATEADD(day,-10,convert(varchar,(getdate()), 111))) and month(DATEADD(day,10,convert(varchar,(getdate()), 111)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work on MS SQL Server. Your modifications are welcome.

```
create procedure dbo.weather
@myDate datetime,
@monthInterval int=1,
@yearsToSearch int=10
as
declare @startDate datetime=dateadd(month,-@monthInterval,@myDate),
@endDate datetime=dateadd(month,@monthInterval,@myDate),
@cnt int=0

declare @tmp table(<your def here>)

while @cnt<=@yearsToSearch
begin
insert @tmp(<field list here>)
select <field list here> from <your_table_here>
where <dateField> between @startDate and @endDate

select @startDate=DATEADD(year,-1,@startDate),@endDate=DATEADD(year,-1,@endDate),@cnt=@cnt+1
end

select * from @tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
;WITH CTE1(StartDate,EndDate) AS
(
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(MONTH,-1,'2016-01-15') AS startDate
      , DATEADD(MONTH,1,'2016-01-15') AS EndDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(YEAR,-1,startDate)
      , DATEADD(YEAR,-1,EndDate)
    FROM CTE1
    WHERE CTE1.StartDate > DATEADD(YEAR,-9,'2016-01-15')
), CTE2 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT columnIDs
    FROM table t
    INNER JOIN cte1 c ON t.date BETWEEN c.StartDate and c.EndDate
)
SELECT *
FROM table t
INNER JOIN cte2 c ON t.columnID = c.columnIDs
```

edit: I don't know how would you have this in your where clause, best I can do is inline function, then you can do an inner join with it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_weather (@startDate datetime, @YearRange int, @MonthRange int)
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN
(WITH CTE1(StartDate,EndDate) AS
(
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(MONTH, -1*@MonthRange, @startDate) AS startDate
      , DATEADD(MONTH, @MonthRange, @startDate) AS EndDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(YEAR,-1,startDate)
      , DATEADD(YEAR,-1,EndDate)
    FROM CTE1
    WHERE CTE1.StartDate > DATEADD(YEAR, -1*(@YearRange-1), @startDate)
)
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM table AS t
INNER JOIN cte1 c ON t.date BETWEEN c.startDate AND c.EndDate)
```

Then you can inner join like any other table

```
INNER JOIN dbo.fn_weather(GETDATE(),10,1) AS fnw ON fnw.ID = table.ID
```

Which will filter out the rows you need.

Comment: Your solution has a hard coded number for how many years can be searched. I mentioned 10 years in my question as an example. Depending on what I'm researching, the number of years depend on what database I'm searching. I was hoping for an answer where I dont have to manually adjust or hard code any numbers. The query would just take my date and how many +- days range I want and then do a search for that range for every year in that database. Thanks for your response though. Maybe I can try to modify your idea.

Comment: Of course you can create a stored procedure and parametrize the solution, this is just a general idea how to get the dataset you need. Replace the -9 with year range, -1/1 with month range, '2016-01-15' with start date. If you want to speed up this query create index on t.date column and include ID column in it.

Comment: I was also hoping to have the solution in form of a where clause because as it is my query already very big. Thanks

Comment: @Bobby - [Hope is the thing with feathers](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poems/detail/42889). If you have _requirements_ then you need to state them in the question. For the benefit of all you should edit the question rather than scattering additional requirements in comments on various answers.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution that is variable driven as a stored procedure ...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetRecordsFromDateRange
    @StartDate as Date,
    @EndDate as Date,
    @numYearsBack as int
as
BEGIN

Declare @useStartDate Date
Declare @useEndDate Date
Set @useStartDate = DATEADD(month,-1,@StartDate)
Set @useEndDate = DATEADD(month,1,@EndDate)

Select
    Data Fields
From table t
Where
    MONTH(t.TableDateColumn) >= MONTH(@useStartDate)
    AND MONTH(t.TableDateColumn) <= MONTH(@useEndDate)
    AND YEAR(t.TableDateColumn) >= YEAR(@useEndDate) - @numYearsBack

END
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

First I create three variables, one for your date, one for your Day-interval and one for your Year-interval.

Then I create 2 temp tables, one with they days and months and one with the possible year.

Then just inner-join the two temp-tables to your selected table.

```
DECLARE @Date AS DATETIME = '2016-01-15'
DECLARE @YearInterval AS INT = 10
DECLARE @DayInterval AS INT = 30

;WITH DayMonthCTE AS (
SELECT
    DATEADD(d, -@DayInterval, @Date) AS myDate
UNION ALL
SELECT
    DATEADD(DAY, 1, myDate) AS myDate
FROM
    DayMonthCTE
WHERE
    DATEADD(DAY, 1, myDate) <= DATEADD(d, @DayInterval, @Date)
)

SELECT
    FORMAT(myDate, 'dd-MM') AS [dayMonth]
INTO
    #DateRange
FROM
    DayMonthCTE
OPTION
    (MAXRECURSION 0)


;WITH YearCTE AS (
SELECT
    YEAR(@Date) - @YearInterval AS myYear
UNION ALL
SELECT
    myYear + 1
FROM
    YearCTE
WHERE
    myYear < YEAR(@Date)
)

SELECT
    myYear AS [Year]
INTO
    #YearRange
FROM
    YearCTE

SELECT
    *
FROM
    YOURTABLE AS D
    INNER JOIN #DateRange AS DR ON FORMAT(D.Date, 'dd-MM') = DR.dayMonth
    INNER JOIN #YearRange AS YR ON YEAR(D.Date) = YR.Year
```